# Is it possible to connect to a docker webapp from public internet while connected to a VPN?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker container that runs a web app. The webapp needs to connect to a test database inside my companies VPN. I need to be able to access this webapp from the public internet.

When I am disconnected from our VPN I can hit the webapp without issue using my public IP assigned by my ISP. Its the IP for my router and I have port forwarding enabled and firewall opened correctly. However its not able to connect to the database.

When I start the VPN the app is able to connect to the database and I can open the pages from the host inside the VPN. However I can no longer access the webapp from the public internet.

Is there some way to allow these connections to come in even while connected to the VPN?

I assume this is a fairly standard use case. In reality I'm oversimplifying and my webapp has dependencies on a slew of services only accessible inside the VPN. I could try to dockerize everything but it would be a pretty massive undertaking. The app needs to be accessible to the public internet because of integrations with 3rd party apps sending webhooks and making API calls back to the webapp.

Comment: Typically you'd deploy the webapp (or a reverse proxy) in a "DMZ" that can access both the public Internet and internal resources.  That sort of deployment question isn't really the sort of programming-oriented question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow, though; consider asking on Server Fault or DevOps.SE.

Comment: I'm a developer not a dev ops guy. Im trying to find ways to develop a webapp with 3rd party integration where they make rest calls to the app as well as webhook calls. The problem with webhooks that so many 3rd party apps offer now is they are a pain to develop code on the localhost. I can deploy the code to our test environment but its no good way to develop software and test the webhook integrations and api calls. I typically like to debug the code rather than an endless cycle of guess coding, deploying to test environment, looking at logs, repeat. It takes 10 times longer to code that way.